# how to delete a table row from database using ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a table with php+mysql, when I click on a delete button, it got deleted but after refreshing the page again, same information gets loaded in the table, 
**So how can I delete from a database permanently with correct id auto change after delete a particular row.Where i have made mistake?** 
Thanks in advance.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.delete').click(function()
    {
        if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this row?"))
        {
            var id = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id');
            var data = 'id=' + id ;
            var parent = $(this).parent().parent();
 
            $.ajax(
            {
                   type: "POST",
                   url: "add_edit1.php",
                   data: data,
                   cache: false,
 
                   success: function()
                   {
                    parent.fadeOut('slow', function() {$(this).remove();});
                   }
             });
        }
    });
 
    // style the table with alternate colors
    // sets specified color for every odd row
    $('table#delTable tr:odd').css('background',' #FFFFFF');
});





</script>
```

```html
<div class="table-responsive">
                    <?php
                    // Include config file
                    require_once 'config.php';
                    
                    // Attempt select query execution
                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM illt";
                    if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
                        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
       
                            echo "<table class='table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed'>";
                                echo "<thead>";
                                    echo "<tr>";
                                        echo "<th>#</th>";
                                        echo "<th>name</th>";
                                        echo "<th>bandwidth</th>";
                                        echo "<th>connectivity</th>";
                                        echo "<th>popname</th>";
          echo "<th>popip</th>";
          echo "<th>port</th>";
          echo "<th>vlan</th>";
          echo "<th>nms</th>";
                                    echo "</tr>";
                                echo "</thead>";
                                echo "<tbody>";
        $count = 1;
                                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                                    echo "<tr>";
                                        echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
                                        echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
                                        echo "<td>" . $row['bandwidth'] . "</td>";
                                        echo "<td>" . $row['connectivity'] . "</td>";
          echo "<td>" . $row['popname'] . "</td>";
          echo "<td>" . $row['popip'] . "</td>";
          echo "<td>" . $row['port'] . "</td>";
          
          echo "<td>" . $row['nms'] . "</td>";
                                        echo "<td>";
          
              echo "<a target = '_blank' href='http://maps.google.com/?q=". $row['latitude'].','. $row['longitude']. "' title='Mapping' data-toggle='tooltip'><i class='material-icons'>&#xE0C8;</i></a>";
                                            echo "</td>";
           
           echo "<td>";
           echo "<a href='readi.php?id=". $row['id'] ."'  title='View Record' data-toggle='tooltip'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open'></span></a>";
                                            echo "<a href='updatei.php?id=". $row['id'] ."'  title='Update Record' data-toggle='tooltip'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></span></a>";
                                            echo "<a href='deletei.php?id=". $row['id'] ."' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#exampleModalLong'  title='Delete Record' data-toggle='tooltip'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span></a>";
                                            echo "<span class='delete' id='del_<?php echo ". $row['id'] ."; ?>'>Delete</span></a>";
   
          echo "</td>";
                                    echo "</tr>";
         
         
         $count++;
         }
         
         
         
                                echo "</tbody>";                            
                            echo "</table>";
                            // Free result set
                            mysqli_free_result($result);
                        } else{
                            echo "<p class='lead'><em>No records were found.</em></p>";
                        }
                    } else{
                        echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
                    }
 

                    // Close connection
                    mysqli_close($link);
                    ?>
     
                </div>
```

*add-edit1.php

```html
<?php 
include "config.php";

if($_POST['id'])
{
$id=mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['id']);
$delete = "DELETE FROM `illt` WHERE id='$id'";
mysqli_query( $delete);
}

?>
```

*

Comment: Is that the full php code? Because you aren't showing any connection to the database. You should also check that the query succeeds.

Comment: i have my database connection in config.php

Comment: but don't you need to include it in the query? like `mysqli_query($conn, $delete)`?

Comment: after adding that also same ,no improvemen

Comment: in the line 'mysqli_query( $delete);'  you have missed to give '$sql' argument in add-edit1.php

Comment: after passing argument also no changes,after refreshing page,the data reloads

Answer (score 0):

1. If you are using mysqli, your first argument in `mysqli_query()` must be `$conn`.
2. Try to change `if($_POST['id'])` to `if(isset($_POST['id']))`.
3. In WHERE clause **id** should be **`id`**
4. Try to set result of `mysqli_query()` to variable (ex. `$result`). Next, check is `$result` equals false, if yes, get last mysqli error by function `mysqli_error($result)`

At the end, your code should be

```
<?php
include "config.php";
if(isset($_POST['id'])){
    $id=mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['id']);
    $delete = "DELETE FROM `illt` WHERE `id`='$id'";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $delete);
    if(!$result){
        echo "MySQLi error: ". mysqli_error($result);
    }
}
?>
```

***If this was useful for you, please rate it**